# Is there an easy way to add handlers to the logger object?

Tags: python, logging

I have to write a code to log messages to a file and to stdout. I read through the logging module and was able to accomplish the task. But just wondering if there is any effective way to do associate handlers to the Logger object?

```
logger = logging.getLogger('TEST')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#create a file handler

file_log_handler = logging.FileHandler('logfile.log',mode='w')
#logger.addHandler(file_log_handler)

#create a stderr_handler

stderr_log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stderr_log_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
#logger.addHandler(stderr_log_handler)

# Create formattar 
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

# Add Handler to Formattar
file_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
stderr_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add logger to Handler
logger.addHandler(file_log_handler,stderr_log_handler)

# application code:

logger.info('debug message')
logger.warning('This is a warning message')
logger.debug('This is a debug message')
logger.error('This is a error message')
```

In the above code, I have two handlers (file_log and stderr_log) and when adding like this

```
logger.addhandler(file_log_handler)
logger.addhandler(stderr_log_handler)
```

works but giving out in a single statement like this:

```
logger.addhandler(file_log_handler,stderr_log_handler)
```

does not work. I tried using it as List as well but no luck.

Is there a efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: No, the API only allows for adding single handler objects. Why is that so inefficient? It is not as if you are adding 1000s of handlers here.

Comment: Thanks @fredtantini .. sorry if I used the word inefficient misappropirately. I was just wondering if supplying multiple handlers to addHandler() is supported or not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, As can be seen in the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1291), the handlers need to be added **safely** (notice [_acquireLock()](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l211) and [_releaseLock()](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l220) because a logger can be shared.

What you could do is the following:

```
logger.handlers.extend([file_log_handler, stderr_handler])
```

But I advise **against** it.

The best way to avoid repetition is what we programmers always do... write a function:

```
def add_many_handlers(logger, handler_list):
    for handler in handler_list:
        logger.addHandler(handler)
```

---

`addHandler` source:

```
def addHandler(self, hdlr):
    """
    Add the specified handler to this logger.
    """
    _acquireLock()
    try:
        if not (hdlr in self.handlers):
            self.handlers.append(hdlr)
    finally:
        _releaseLock()
```

Comment: Thanks @Reut Sharabani. This helps !!